# Can't search files in python

Tags: python, file-io

The code

```
f = open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\OneDrive\\Documents\\CS project 12th\\Command.txt", "r")
g = open("C:\\Users\\Administrator\\OneDrive\\Documents\\CS project 12th\\Reply.txt","r")
list1 = f.readlines()
list2 = g.readlines()
st = 'hello'
index = 0
for i in f:
    if st in i:
        print("Found it")
    else:
        print("Not found")
```

So what this is supposed to do is to search for a string in file f

[The file F](https://i.stack.imgur.com/INLP1.png)

but it returns a blank output.

Any reason as to why this is happening.

Comment: check first if file exist or not `os.path.exists(filepath)`

Comment: Didn't you mean `for i in list1`?

Comment: Yeah i wanna use it without readlines just ignore the list1 and list 2 part. I intended to not use readlines to make the code run faster for another project. and the file exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you used `readlines`, that takes the lines out of the files, instead try:

```
for i in list1:
    if st in i:
        print("Found it")
    else:
        print("Not found")
```

Comment: Yeah i wanna use it without readlines just ignore the list1 and list 2 part. I intended to not use readlines to make the code run faster for another project

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer it was because i was using readlines which made the cursor position at end and the search returned nothing.
In short, the fix was to remove the readline, read or any i/o reading command.